# jQuery Code that populates <input> textbox with items from a table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

jQuery Code that populates  textbox with items by fetching existing ids from a table does not seem to be working. When I type a value in the input the dropdown with the option values does not appear.Maybe I am using the wrong element in the dropdown?

HTML:

```
  <label>ID* 
    <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" />
  </label>
```

JQUERY:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'pcfform.aspx/GetIds',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#firstName").append("<option label='" + results.d[i] +
                        "' value='" + results.d[i] + "'></option>");
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**aspx:**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using PCF.Entities;
using PCF.Entities.Data;
 namespace PCF.Pages
 {
     public partial class pcfform : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
      [WebMethod]
      public static string[] GetIds() 
      {
          PCF.Entities.Data.Entities db = new   PCF.Entities.Data.Entities();
          var data = (from item in db.MasterTables 
                   where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FirstName))
                   select item.FirstName).Distinct();
        return data.ToArray(); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `does not seem to be working` is not conveying anything. What is the error? Be Specific.

Comment: Am I using the right element? Code in pcfform gets the data but the dropdown does appear when input value in input box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, you have figured out the issue, i see two problems in your code. First the dropdown should be a `select` control and not input text control:-

```
<select id="lifeNumber" name="lifeNumber" />
```

Second, in your success callback, you are using this to populate your dropdown:-

```
$("#firstName")
```

But, firstName in your control is `name` attribute and not id, so it should be:-

```
$("#lifeNumber").append(..
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add a datalist. Now dropdown appears with options

```
 <input id="firstName1" type="text" list="firstName" size="26" maxlength="20" name="firstName" tabindex="2" />
                                <datalist id="firstName" ></datalist>
```